# Installing AMD/ATI Radeon R9 290 graphics card

Tags: memory, graphics-card, bios, gpu

I am trying to upgrade my desktop system with an ATI Radeon R9 290 graphics card.
The first time I boot with it plugged in, it doesn't even show the BIOS splash screen (the one with the `press <F2> for BIOS` message), it simply shows a blank screen and

```
98% of system memory tested OK.

Press ENTER to skip memory test
```

If I hit enter, the screen flickers slightly, the message stays and the 'code' `B8_` appears in the bottom right. And then it just stays put like that. If I force restart with the power button, it just cuts to a black screen with `B8_`.

I've tried removing all but 1Gb of RAM, and it behaves the same way, with the exception that initially it says

```
The firmware detected that the system memory has decreased.

Press ENTER to continue
```

Besides, I know my RAM is fine because I can use it with other graphics cards just fine!

I've checked the integrated GPU fan, and that's running normally all the time.

What could be the issue?

EDIT:

My motherboard is an `Intel DP35DP`. The `B8` error code is `Resetting removable media` according to [the Intel website](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-025434.htm). Honestly, I don't know what this means...

I checked the specs for the power supply, a `Cooler Master RS-850-SPM2`, and it can supply up to 68 Ampères at +12 Volts, which is enough for the graphics card wich needs at least 24A.

Comment: Did you connect **all** power connectors?

Comment: Yes. The GPU has an adaptor, which I used, and a second power connector, also plugged in.

Comment: OK. Just asking since that is the most common error. Other question: Which motherboard do you have? Look at up and then look up what the error code means. Add that to your post. While you are at it, how many amps +12v can the PSU supply? How much does the card need?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I checked the specs for MB and PSU (see edit)

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what I wrote aobut the `B8_ ` in the questioin is correct - I got that from the list of `Port 80h POST codes`, and [Intel suggests](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-025434.htm#port80h) using a special PCI board to find out about those, not looking on the screen. It might not actually be a `Port 80h POST code` I'm getting...